# running rake task from console produces 'ArgumentError: no method name given' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rake, actionmailer, rails-console

I have a rake task that is meant to call a Mailer and email certain users that meet a given condition.  But, when I call the rake task from the console using `rake nagging_email:send`
 I get the following 'ArgumentError: no method name given' and the task does not run.  The full console error log can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/srt32/6433024

I have a mailer set up as follows:

```
class WorkoutMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def nagging_email(user)
      @user = user
      subject = "What have you done today?"
      @url = 'http://frozen-taiga-7141.herokuapp.com/members/sign_in'

      mail to: @user.email,
        subject: subject.to_s
    end
end
```

and then a rake task as follows that gets all the users that meet a given condition (being lazy) and then calls the Mailer given that user as a param:

```
namespace :nagging_email do
  desc "send nagging email to lazy users"
  task :send => :environment do
    daily_nag
  end

  def daily_nag
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      unless last_workout(user) == Date.today
        WorkoutMailer.nagging_email(user).deliver
      end
    end
  end

  def last_workout(user)
    user = user
    last_workout = user.workouts.order("date DESC").limit(1)
    last_workout_date = last_workout.date
    return last_workout_date
  end
end
```

Any help trying to figure out how run this rake task would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: one way is to define daily_nag as rake task and then invoke it inside send task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run rake from terminal, not rails console.
If you for some reason want to do it from rails console, you should load tasks like that

```
require 'rake'
MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks 
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```